# AnguarJS/ javascript combine two arrays with same length together

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, for-loop

I'm trying to combine two arrays with same length array1 (users array) is a user list.. array2 (boolean array) is a list of boolean values generated from http status (if success = true / if error false).. i know it's a little bit weird how it's setup but that's what the backed developer provided.. just have to make use what he gives.. for brevity purposes data model of the GetUseFollowers service returns a to_id and from_id that's why i have t getUserById..

Data Model:

```
$scope.users = [{id:1, username="foo"}, {id:2, username="bar"}];
$scope.check = [{true,false}]; //there is no key does it even count as an array?
```

Desired output:

```
$scope.users = [{id:1, username="foo", is_following: true},{id:2, username="bar", is_following: false}]
```

---

```
 $scope.check = []; // array with boolean values
var checkIfFollowing= function(id){
  UserService.CheckIfFollowing($stateParams.id, id,)
        .success(function (data) {
          var check = true;
        $scope.check.push(check);
          }).
        error(function(error, status) {
          var check = false;
        $scope.check.push(check);      
      });
}

  $scope.users = []; // users array 
  var getUser = function(id) {
        UserService.GetUserById(id, $localStorage.CurrentUser.auth_token)
        .success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = angular.fromJson(data);   
        $scope.users.push($scope.data);
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete')
        console.log(angular.toJson($scope.users));

        }).error(function(error, status) {
            alert(status);
            console.log(error);         
        });
    };

 $scope.GetUserFollowers = function() {
  UserService.GetUserFollowers($stateParams.id, -1, 0, 6)
        .success(function (data) {
         console.log(data);             
         data = angular.fromJson(data);

         angular.forEach(data, function(user){
          checkIfFollowing(user.from_user) //create array check            
          getUser(user.from_user) //create array users                          
         });       

          }).
        error(function(error, status) {
          alert(status);
          console.log(error);         
      });

        }
```

Comment: `[{true,false}]` is not valid JavaScript. Maybe you want `[true,false]`?

Comment: @dave could you please provide a code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge these arrays using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Here's a quick example without Angular.

```js
var users = [{id:1, username:"foo"}, {id:2, username:"bar"}];
var check = [true,false];
var merged = users.map(function(value, index) {
  var newValue = value;
  newValue.is_following = check[index];
  return newValue;
});
console.log(merged);
```

Comment: the issue now is...the association of the is_following is not to the same user all the time.. for example first request {username:"dave" is_following:true} second request {username:"dave" is_following:false}.. do you know what could be cauusing the issue

Comment: i think i need to associate an id with my boolean array so that i could compare if user id and boolean array id is the same.. because the view renders the list randomly for some reason

Comment: `Array.map()` [guarantees order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description), so there must be something else causing your inconsistent results.

Comment: yeah i actually had to associate an id to the boolean then compare 2 arrays crossreference ids thanks!